# Where does output of echo go to in php

Tags: php, wordpress

We have a wordpress site which has a php script using echo for some status messages.

The script is called from the net, and all it does is format some received data and write it to a database on the site.

There are some performance issues and I want to output some specific debug information, timings etc, but as I'm not the one who created this script and I have no experience with php, I can't figure out where the output of the echo goes.

The question is: where does it go, and more importantly, can I display it, or even redirect it to a file ?

Snippet of the code:

```
function AddHost()
{
    global $DB_host, $DB_name, $DB_username, $DB_password;

    // added 10.10.05 for testing 
    if (isset($_POST['test']))
    {
        if ($_POST['test'] == '1')
        {
            echo "TEST SUCCEEDED";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "TEST FAILED";
        }
        exit;
    }
```

Comment: By default it goes to stdout. Where exactly *that* goes depends on how the script is run. How are you running the script? As a regular .php site through a web server?

Comment: it is configurable. Show us the script.

Comment: code added.

Yes, regular site through web server

Comment: In simple: `echo` outputs text to browser, so all your `echo "TEST ..."` will be visible

Comment: Then you should see it as response to the HTTP request. For a regular website that means *on the website*. For an AJAX request it means in the response body of the request, which you can access programmatically or see in the network inspector.